dont work the Google Apps script redirection and data comparison from google sheets
I created a site in Google Sites, which is: https://sites.google.com/view/appuntiig/home, when you open it at the register button I connected a Google Forms file which does the registration and sends me the data recording in a Google Sheets file. then I created a web app with Google Apps Script in the log in button which practically when I press log in the program starts and asks me for my email and password if they are correct, it redirects me to a page, I enter the codes I used:
(code.gs)
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('login');
}

function doPost(e) {
var email = e.parameter.email;
var password = e.parameter.password;

Verifica delle credenziali nel foglio di Google Sheets
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID').getSheetByName('Utenti_registrati');
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

var loggedIn = false;

for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
if (data[i][0] == email && data[i][1] == password) {
loggedIn = true;
break;
    }
  }

if (loggedIn) {
Reindirizza l'utente alla pagina desiderata su Google Sites dopo il login
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Login riuscito! Reindirizzamento in corso...</p><script>window.location.href = "https://sites.google.com/view/appuntiig/visualizza-appunti";</script>');
else {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Email o password errati. Riprova.</p>');
  }
}

(login.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>">
Email: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Accedi">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
> 

only that when I enter the email and password that are already in the Google Sheets file and I log in from the button it gives me this message:

An error occurred in Google Docs. Try reloading the page or visiting it again in a few minutes.
To learn more about Google Docs editors, visit our Help Center.
We apologize for the inconvenience.

The Google Docs team


What can I do to solve it? Do you have any ideas?

Morning :) did you deploy the web-app using the Execute the app as me permission?

yes i execute as me and everyone have access
